# Can an element hood test be converted into an existential statement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm just curious whether it makes sense to convert a statement of the form: 
$$ y\in \{x\in A : \phi(x) \} \;\; \text{into the form} \;\; \exists x(\,...) $$
It's just that in the book I'm reading the author says that one can convert the expression:

$$ x\in \{n^2:n\in\mathbb{N} \} \;\; \text{into} \;\; \exists n \in \mathbb{N}(x=n^2)$$
but I can't see how to apply this to my case since:
$$ y\in \{x\in A : \phi(x) \} \rightarrow y\in \{x :x \in A \land \phi(x) \} $$ 
doesn't seem to lend itself to being in the form that makes sense when converting it to the existential form according to the book. What I want to write is $\exists y(y\in A \land \phi(y))$ since we've defined a set based on some conditions and if $y$ is in that set it must meet those conditions but the expression doesn't have a free variable which I would assume would be required. I guess this is a little closer to the book $\exists x(x\in A\land \phi(x)\land x=y)$ but it seems rather strange to just state $x=y$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It makes sense. I would even argue that it makes *more sense*, because something like $\{n^2\colon n\in\mathbb{N} \}$ requires the axiom of replacement to be proved to be a set where as something like $\{x\in \mathbb N\colon \exists n\in \mathbb N(x=n^2)\}$ doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{x\in A : \phi(x)\}$ is by definition the set whose members are exactly anything that is a member of $A$ and satisfies $\phi$.

So $y\in\{x\in A:\phi(x)\}$ *means* just $y\in A\land \phi(y)$. You don't need any quantifier here. You want the variable $y$ to be free in the unfolding, just as it is free in "$y\in \cdots$".

---

The $\{n^2:n\in N\}$ case is a different construction. It doesn't have the form $\{x\in A : \phi(x)\}$ but instead $\{f(x):x\in A\}$, so therefore you need a different construction (which does need to involve a quantifier) to unfold it.

Formally, if you get down to the axioms of set theory, the two notations are justified by different axioms. $\{x\in A : \phi(x)\}$ invokes the *Axiom of Separation* (also variously called the axiom of "subsets", "selection", or "comprehension"), whereas $\{f(x):x\in A\}$ invokes the *Axiom of Replacement*. The notation looks alike for reasons of making it easier to remember what they mean, but formally they are different things that need to be handled in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes a lot of sense. I'm just getting to grips with the syntax of set theory and logic but the book hasn't explained the difference between the two constructions very well so I'll read up on the axioms. Just to clarify with the construction $\{f(x):x\in A\}$ does that take values of $x$ from $A$ and then outputs $f(x)$. For example with $f(x)=2x$ and $A=\{1,2\}$ applying the above set construction would give the set: $\{2,4\}$. Again thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jay: Correct. Note that sometimes the notations are combined, for example as $\{2x:x\in A, x>0\}$ where there's both a function and filtering involved. It could be written more primitively as $\{2x:x\in\{y\in A:y>0\}\}$, but the shorter version is usually easier to read.